# cx frozen application works fine in some systems and throws Importerror in other systems

Tags: python, tkinter, importerror, cx-freeze

I have a GUI application, written in Python using `Tkinter` library.

I froze this application using `cx_Freeze`.

This application works fine in my Windows 7 OS machine, and many members in my team using Windows 7, and do not have Python in their machines. But there are many others who have Windows 7 OS, but this application throws `ImportError` exception.

[image]

At line 16 in the code, I am importing `ibm_db` library.

Please suggest what could be the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you have a ibm_db.dll and where its located. Then check the same thing on your Members system (where it throws `ImportError`). Is there any difference?

Comment: Have you verified all of the DLL library dependencies are satisfied on the systems where it doesn't work? (dependency walker is a good tool to do this)

Comment: @VRage: cx_Freeze created a folder named build. I zipped that folder and shared with everyone. So, everyone is getting the same set of files in the same folder. No difference in folder structure.

Comment: But can you be sure that cx_freeze doesn't use a dll located in your c:\windows folder?

Comment: @Matt : Actually we have more or less the same office issued laptops. same Windows version I am exploring on Dependency Walker. Let me see if I find anything.

Comment: @VRage: `cx_Freeze` is using `ibm_db` package located at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` folder while freezing the application. After this when I run the `.exe` file created by `cx_Freeze`, it uses `ibm_db` package from the `build` folder only - (I tested this by renaming the Python27 folder)